# Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, .net-core

I am trying to import some `.dll` files from my app to my powershell script. 
There are two dll's: `MyProject.dll` and `MyProject.Data.dll`. I can succesfully load the first dll, which i an access one of the ENUMS there. But the problem is that when I am trying to load the second one its throwing this error:

> Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And here is what my script looks like:

```
Import-Module "./dll/MyProject.dll"
Import-Module "./dll/MyProject.Data.dll" # error while loading this one.


$global:admin_role = [MyProject.UserRole]::Admin
$global:super_user_role = [MyProject.UserRole]::SuperUser


$user_account = New-Object MyProject.Data.UserAccount
```

Just for your info i got the dll's from `MyProject.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2` which contains all dll's.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your dll's using Add-Type:

```
Add-Type -Path .\dll\MyProject.dll
Add-Type -Path .\dll\MyProject.Data.dll
```

Comment: There is no parameter `Type`. Here it is what Add-Type includes: `Add-Type [-TypeDefinition] <string> [-CodeDomProvider <CodeDomProvider>] [-CompilerParameters <CompilerParameters>] [-Language <Language>] [-ReferencedAssemblies <string[]>] [-OutputAssembly <string>] [-OutputType <OutputAssemblyType>] [-PassThru] [-IgnoreWarnings] [<CommonParameters>]`